# How do I check for EOF in C?

Tags: c, file-io, eof

I have a text file with lines of numbers for example

```
 5  6  3 2 10  4 6 
18 49 40 9 17 40 0
```

And when I read in the file it doesn't stop at the end of file. my code for the loop reading in is as below -

```
while ((fscanf(spFile, "%d", &scores[i][j])) == 1 && spFile != EOF) {
        printf("%d ", scores[i][j]);

        if(j == 8) {
            i++;
            j = 0;
            printf("\n");
        } else {
            j++;
        }
        numOfStudents++;
    }
```

the maximum number of rows is 50(so an array of 50(have to have this as array not pointer)) and I have numOfStudents to count the number of rows, when it finishes it says 50 when it really only has 2.

Thanks!

Comment: check the standard `feof` function... (this is homework?)

Comment: Perhaps you should check the return code?  (And before that, check the spec.)

Comment: Increase the warning level of your compiler and **mind the warnings**. `spFile` is a pointer; `EOF` is an integer: your compiler will helpfully warn you about comparing values of types that cannot be compared.

Comment: You can check if `fscanf()` has returned a value `> 0` too.

Comment: This makes no sense: `spFile != EOF`

Comment: yeaa I've been trying to figure it out forever >: I'll check the feof.

Comment: ' I've been trying to figure it out forever' -- But without ever reading the scanf documentation, apparently.

Comment: This loop *will* stop upon EOF, but it will stop for other reasons too, e.g., if the file contains something that isn't an integer.

Answer (score 2):

fscanf() will return 0 or EOF.

You can also use the "feof()" function.

The file pointer variable, spFile, will *never* equal EOF.  "EOF" is a state managed by the C runtime, it's not the file pointer itself.

Comment: Theoretically pointer spFile can be EOF (-1), which represents maximum address the pointer can hold.

Answer (score 0):

The condition for the loop should be like this:

```
while (fscanf(spFile, "%d", &scores[i][j]) > 0){
   /* Do Stuff */
}
```

or, to avoid the case where you can't parse the input :

```
while (!feof(spFile) && fscanf(spFile, "%d", &scores[i][j]) > 0){
   /* Do Stuff */
}
```

Comment: @paulsm4 I guess it may have been that the result isn't saved so one can't check inside the loop if anything was actually read.

Comment: What if the input file contains a character that cannot be parsed as either whitespace or part of an integer? `fscanf()` will never return `EOF` in that case and will be stuck in a loop returning `0` for ever and ever.

Comment: True.  @Rami Jarrar - if you look at the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/) for scanf, you'll see that it can return 1) the #/items it successfully read (> 0), 2) EOF (< 0) or invalid data (0).  It *is* possible to get stuck in an infinite loop with your code.  But I upvoted you anyway - I think multiple downvotes is a bit harsh :)

Comment: @Rami Jarrar - thanx for the modifications.  Hopefully the others might reconsider their downvotes :)

Comment: Your update does not solve the problem. I think you meant **!feof()**. `while (!feof(spFile) && fscanf(spFile, "%d", &scores[i][j]) != EOF)` is still an infinite loop if there's "strange" data in the input.

Comment: @RamiJarrar Er, you're still not checking that it actually manages to read the integer. You're just double checking for EOF.

Comment: Why not the simpler `while(fscanf(...) == 1)`?

Comment: aha,, yeah I should check for `>0`.

Comment: I recommend ditching `fscanf()` -- use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead :)

Comment: @pmg 'will be stuck in a loop returning 0 for ever and ever' -- no, 0 != 1 so the loop would terminate.

Comment: @JimBalter: I was referring to a previous version of the code: `while (scanf(...) != EOF)`. Both `1` and `0` are `!= EOF`

Comment: @pmg No edit of the code is shown. I guess it's the idiotic SO misfeature that only shows edits that occur after 2 minutes. ... edit: oops, I'm talking about the OP's code, you're talking about this answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try by checking if number of bytes returned by `fscanf()` is greater than `0`:

```
while(fscanf(...) > 0) {
/* do something */
}
```

With error checkding is something like this:

```
while(1) {
  fscanf( .. );

  if(feof(fp)) {
    if(ferror(fp)) {
        /* stoped because an error check out errno */
    }

   break;
  }
```